# Select by expression error

Tags: qgis, select-by-attribute

I am trying to create new shapefiles from an existing shapefile using QGIS 2.18. On getting to the select by expression box which I am doing by states, a state name appears twice. I have checked the attribute table of the shapefile I am creating the selection from and checked the spelling as well but I seem can not find what the problem is. How do I rectify this?

Comment: Could it be whitespaces after the name?

Comment: I checked that by clicking inside the box to reduce the space.

Comment: I just checked and tried again and it worked. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Select all the features with that state name. Change the "state name" field value to the correct value for all the selected features, using the Field Calculator or multiedit line in the attribute table.

[image]